# Soap API - How to get request by Limit 10 based on pagination?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap-api-v2, time, mvc

I am getting products list using **catalogProductList**, its taking too long time to return the values(see screenshot) actually my products count is 24K, how can i run by using limit 10 and if i click page 2 then only load next 10 (Now load everything then only print the value).

Now my design look like,

[image]

Code :

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('www.abc.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1');
        $sessionId = $proxy->login((object)array('username' => 'abc', 'apiKey' => 'abc123'));
        $result = $proxy->catalogProductList((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'filters' => null));      
        return $result->result();
```

Note : **https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4**

**How to run API  soap v2 as limit 10, and should be next 10 load when i click page 2?**

Comment: you have custom product collection getting? and currently pagination working or not

Comment: Not Custom product collection, getting all products and pagination working.

Comment: please add your code in your question

Comment: @RakeshDonga Just now updated with code. I am using  https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4   in my codeigniter.

Comment: you have try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32745817/10748606

Comment: also this work for you i think 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10720932/10748606

Comment: Let me know if you have any confusion for implementation.

Comment: how to configure with my DataTables-bootstrap in CodeIgniter?

Comment: working now or not ?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately as far as I know you can't simply pass a limit to the SOAP API.

One approach which would work if you don't need to filter the list by any attributes, want to get all attributes and have no missing entity_ids for products (i.e. you have never deleted a product).
This is the approach to get **bunches of x products based on the maximum entity_id and a given page**.

Anyway if the above assumptions are not acceptable for your requirement, you shouldn't use it :-)

```
//soap v2
$client = new SoapClient('http://yoursite/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1');

$session = $client->login('login', 'password');

//get the maximum entity_id from your database
$maxID = 101; 

//get your page parameter beginning with 1 for the first page
$page = 2; 

 //set your pagesize
$pageSize = 20;

//this is thenumber of pages you will get
$pagesInPagination = ceil ($maxID / $pageSize);

$start = $maxID - ($page - 1) * $pageSize;

$end = $start - $pageSize;

$entityIdList = [];
for ($i = $start; $i > $end; $i--){
    $entityIdList[] = $i;
}


$complexFilter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'entity_id',
            'value' => array('key' => 'in', 'value' => implode (',',$entityIdList))
        ),
    )
);
$result = $client->catalogProductList($session, $complexFilter);

foreach($result as $product) {
    $data = (array) $product;
    echo $data['product_id']. "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
error_reporting(-1); 
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
class Live_stock extends CI_Controller { 

public function index() 
{ 


$this->load->view("header_view"); 

$proxy = new SoapClient('abc.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1'); // TODO : change url 
$sessionId = $proxy->login((object)array('username' => 'abc', 'apiKey' => 'abc123')); 
$result["productArray"] = $proxy->catalogProductList((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'filters' => null)); 
$this->load->view("live_stock_view",$result); 

$this->load->view("footer_view"); 



} 
}
```

*here limit code also available*

```
$in = array();
for ($i = ($page * $size) - $size; $i < ($page * $size); $i++) {
    $in[] = $i + 1;
}
$complexFilter = array('complex_filter' => 
    array(
        array(
            'key' => 'product_id',
            'value' => array(
                'key' => 'in', 
                'value' => join(",", $in)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10720932/10748606)

Comment: @ZUS i have updated my answer